# Get file URL from root folder ID using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
var Files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Filename);
while(Files.hasNext()) {...}
```

Above code searches every drive files and returns file whenever the name matches with Filename but there could be repeated filenames which **I personally think very inefficient**.

**Assuming User know followings**,

1. Root Folder ID
2. File Name

Is there anyway to get File URL by something like below code?

```
var FileURL = DriveApp.OpenFolder(FolderID).getFileByName(Filename).getURL();
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `getRootFolder()` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getrootfolder)

Comment: @Tedinoz Nope, I will look for the getRootFolder() Docs. Just curious whether such function can be used.

Comment: `but there could be repeated filenames` - Indeed, and there could be repeated filenames in a single folder. `getFileByName(Filename)` returns just **one** file but doesn't tell you whether there are multiple files by that name; `getFilesByName(name)` will return **ALL** the files with that name. Also, `getFilesByName(name)` can be run from `DriveApp` or from a specific folder.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for the point. I didn't consider the file repetition case in single root folder. If so, is there any way to get latest file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search for files by filtering for the parents.
To search for a specific set of files or folders, use the query string `q` with `files.list` to filter the files to return.

One example in Python would be:

```
response = self.service.files().list(q="'"+ myfoldername +"' in parents").execute()
```

where `service` is the Google Drive API instance.

Described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#specific